# Why is SetAppearance in ShellNavBarAppearanceTracker not virtual while the same method in ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker is?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have tried to create my own appearance trackers for the navigation bar and tab bar for my custom Shell renderer in iOS. Overriding the SetAppearance method for the TabBar appearance tracker is allowed, while the same for the NavigationBar appearance tracker is not. Why is this?

Comment: I am still waiting to build again on iOS. I don't have access to a Mac today, but I will be able to determine if your answer worked tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see the source codes of `ShellNavBarAppearanceTracker`

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS
{
  public class ShellNavBarAppearanceTracker : IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker, IDisposable
  {
    public ShellNavBarAppearanceTracker();

    public void Dispose();
    public void ResetAppearance(UINavigationController controller);
    public void SetAppearance(UINavigationController controller, ShellAppearance appearance);
    public virtual void SetHasShadow(UINavigationController controller, bool hasShadow);
    public void UpdateLayout(UINavigationController controller);
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
  }
}
```

`SetAppearance` method is  `public` not `virtual`.So you couldn't overwrite `SetAppearance` drectly.

If you want to overwrite the `SetAppearance` method,you could implement `IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker`.

```
class MyNavBarAppearanceTracker : IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void ResetAppearance(UINavigationController controller)
        {
        }

        public void SetAppearance(UINavigationController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
        }

        public void SetHasShadow(UINavigationController controller, bool hasShadow)
        {
        }

        public void UpdateLayout(UINavigationController controller)
        {
        }
    }
```